# Rspec test for destroy if no delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm going through the latest rails tutorial on railstutorial.org and I am stuck on a certain exercise (#8 on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec:updating_deleting_exercises).  You have to write a rspec/capybara test to make sure the admin can't delete themself.  I have the implementation working, but can't get the test to work right.  Here is my code.  I found similar questions here: [Ruby on Rails syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510204/ruby-on-rails-syntax) and https://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/how_to_prevent_admin_user_from_deleting_themselves .  But I think it is an older tutorial and not the same question.

Here is the relevant code in spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:

```
describe "User pages" do
  subject { page }
    describe "delete links" do
      describe "as an admin user" do
        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before do
          sign_in admin
          visit users_path
        end
        it "should not be able to delete themself" do
          expect { admin.delete }.should_not change(User, :count)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error message says that the user count is getting reduced by 1.

For completeness, here is my (working) implementation:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :current_admin,     only: :destroy
  def current_admin
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to users_path, notice: "Cannot delete current admin" if current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

Where am I going wrong, thanks?  (I left out some methods, but hopefully there is enough to figure out what I'm trying to do)

Edit: Using Ruby v1.9.3, Rails v3.2.3.  By default, there is no delete link for admins.

Edit2: Here is what I got working:

spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  describe "admins" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

    it "should not be able to delete themself" do
      sign_in admin
      expect { delete :destroy, :id => admin.id }.should_not change(User, :count)
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if current_user?(@user)
    flash[:error] = "Cannot delete current admin"
  else
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
  end
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax of your before_filter is incorrect. The call should look like this

```
before_filter :current_admin, :only => [:destroy]
```

You would also probably be better off keeping this logic in the destroy action. Since it only applies to that action, I don't see any reason to move it into a separate method/filter. The other questions you pointed to are in fact from older versions of the tutorial, but the logic is nonetheless the same:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if current_user?(@user)
      flash[:error]  = "Cannot delete current admin"
    else
      user.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "User was successfully deleted"
    end

    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

As for your test, it's failing because you are calling the delete method instead of the destroy action in your controller. From [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete)

> Active Record objects are not instantiated, so the object’s callbacks
>   are not executed, including any :dependent association options or
>   Observer methods.

Since they're asking you to use rspec/capybara, you can use the click_link method to trigger the destroy action. Since you're on an index page with multiple listings, you should look into [Capybara::Node::Finders](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders) in order to select the correct button reliably.

Edit: Since you're looking to test the controller, not the view, you can test with:

```
describe "admins" do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }

   it "should not be able to delete themself" do
     sign_in admin
     expect { delete :destroy, :id => admin.id }.should_not change(User, :count)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will play around with your answer and see if it works.  However, by default, there is no link for the destroy action for admins.  So I do not think I can use the click_link method.  Also, when I added a delete link for admins, to test my controller, my before_filter was working.  Yet, it might not be the best way to do it.  I am thinking that my subject might not be correct because I am not really testing the page, but the controller.

Comment: You can use "delete :destroy" to call your destroy action directly. I've added an example in the answer

Comment: current_user method does not exist for tests.  Maybe I should write one.  Is there another way using the admin object?  Should I move the added test to a different file, like spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb?

Comment: I would definitely use a controller spec instead of a request spec if you don't need to test the full stack for this one feature.

I shouldn't have assumed you had a current_user method, and I've updated the code; it should work now. I believe the tutorial leads you to implement a current_user method eventually.

Answer (score 8):

This can be tested in the user_pages_spec which is pretty much what the railstutorial.org book seems to want you to do.  (Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 9, Exercise 9).  Whether that is a good idea I leave up to greater minds.

The test code in user_pages_spec.rb would look like this:

```
 describe "I should not be able to delete admins" do
      before { delete user_path(admin.id) }

      it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Admins cannot delete themselves') }
    end
```

the delete user_path(admin.id) will mimic clicking 'delete' and works in rspec-capybara. This will pass with your controller code above, assuming you change your error message to match mine or vice-versa.

Also, the before_filter syntax in the UsersController seems to work either with or without the [] if there is only item.

Comment: Testing whether there is an error message seems flimsy.  As you alluded to if I change the string and forget to update the test, that would lead to a false positive.  What makes more sense to me would be something more like: `expect { delete user_path(admin.id) }.should_not change (User, :count)`