# I'm learning Rails with M. Hartl's Tutorial. Ch. 11.2.5 and got this error in tests: ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec

Full error messages:

```
1) RelationshipsController creating a relationship with Ajax should increment the     Relationship count
Failure/Error: xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
# ./spec/requests/relationships_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/relationships_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) RelationshipsController creating a relationship with Ajax should respond with success
Failure/Error: xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
# ./spec/requests/relationships_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) RelationshipsController destroying a relationship with Ajax should decrement the Relationship count
Failure/Error: xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
# ./spec/requests/relationships_controller_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/requests/relationships_controller_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) RelationshipsController destroying a relationship with Ajax should respond with success
Failure/Error: xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
# ./spec/requests/relationships_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

[My github for source of code](https://github.com/loveisdapowah/sample_app)

In browser AJAX works fine but tests is red. :(

I'm pretty new to programming, Rails and Stackowerflow.
Please help me to solve this problem. :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:
[RSpec test destroy method (Rails Tutorial 3.2 Ch. 9, Ex. 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989427/rspec-test-destroy-method-rails-tutorial-3-2-ch-9-ex-10)

I'd also read further down in the link above; you should make maximum use of Capybara instead of mixing rspec with methods provided by Rails for `Action*::TestCase`.  Do this instead

> you can use capybara's `page.execute_script` (but you have to enable
>   javascript for this example `:js => true`)

Comment: Sorry, but i want use method exactly as in Rails Tutorial. For example "xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }". And want to know why test are red wis thes line of code.

Comment: That's exactly my point, you really shouldn't be using the `xhr` method if you can help it.  Go refer it up @ http://api.rubyonrails.org.  It's listed under `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`...but you're using RSpec!  If you were say using `Test::Unit` or `MiniTest`, then it's a different story.  Hence the suggestion to use Capybara to make the AJAX request.  Hartl shouldn't be encouraging this!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue following the same Ajax section of Chapter 11 in the RailsTutorial(with Rails 3.2). I think Michael de Silva was right in that the xhr were unfortunately mixed with the RSpec here.

Anyways, I decided that for the sake of completeness (I'm almost done with the tutorial) - I was going to get xhr to somehow work here. I think Mike Hartl's Listing 11.37 should have used the ActionDispatcher::Integration::RequestHelpers method xhr, as in 
 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-xhr

rather than the ActionController::TestCase::Behavior method xhr, as in
 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-xhr

So I replaced the reference to actions :create and :destroy with their named routes and the test examples in Listing 11.37 turned green. The original

```
expect do
  xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
```

becomes,

```
expect do
  xhr :post, relationships_path, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
```

and, the original

```
expect do
  xhr :delete, :destroy, id: relationship.id
end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
```

becomes,

```
expect do
  xhr :delete, relationship_path(relationship.id), id: relationship.id
end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(-1)
```